# how to write this linear transformation as a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was trying to write this linear transformation as a matrix,
the exercise is the following:
let "f: $R^3 --> R^4$" be a linear transformation and Kerf = (x, y , z) in $R^3$: $x-2y+z = 0$  is its null space. Determine the canonical matrix.

I know how to solve this type of exercises (generally), as follow:

1. I use the basis of the first vector space (R3 in this case),
2. I plug x, y, z, in the equations of the linear transformation,
3. then, I'm ready to use each component of the vectors (of R4, in this case) to create the matrix. (the canonical matrix has basis of the entire space, for example, 1 0 0, 0 1 0, 0 0 1).

But, when I'm about to solve these exercises, I simply cannot solve them. I don't know why, because I know how to do them theoretically.

Can you help me to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{ker}A$ is the set of vectors $\vec x$ that satisfy $A\vec x=0.$ And you are given that $x-2y+z = 0.$ So, if we let $\alpha=z,\ \beta =y$ then $x=2\beta-\alpha$ and so $\vec x=(2\beta-\alpha,\beta,\alpha)^T.$ Collecting this information in a slightly different way, $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y 
\\ z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\0 
\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}\alpha+\begin{pmatrix}
2\\1 
\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}\beta.$ Set $\vec v_1 = (-1,0,1)^T$ and $\vec v_2=(2,1,0)^T$ and extend to a basis for $\mathbb R^3:$ we may take $\vec v_3=(0,0,1)^T.$

So, in the basis $\{\vec v_1,\ \vec v_2,\ \vec v_3\}$, we have $A\vec v_1=A\vec v_2=0$ and $A\vec v_3=(a,b,c,d)^T$ for some numbers $a,b,c,d.$ The matrix of $A$ in this basis relative to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^4$ is therefore

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &a\\ 
0 &0  &b \\ 
 0&0  &c \\ 
0 &0  &d 
\end{pmatrix}.$

Now we compute the change of basis matrix $[\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3]\to [\vec i,\vec j,\vec k]:$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 2 &0 \\ 
 0& 1 &0 \\ 
1 & 0 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix of $A$ relative to the standard bases for $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^4$ is therefore $AB$.

Comment: I have a question: why did you use the transpose when you had to write the set of vectors?

Comment: Row vectors are the transpose of column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint or perhaps a topic you will want to understand better. What is the vector corresponding to your transformation (x-2y+z) and why?